# Hosting a node application as a subdomain of a regular site

Tags: node.js, heroku, dreamhost, server

I have a website hosted by dreamhost. I have a static website hosted there (html/css/js).

I also have a node app that I have developed and run locally.

I want to have this app live in a subdomain like nodeapp.brandon.com (for example -- not my website).

Is there a method to achieve this? I have considered redirecting to a service like heroku or something similar.

Comment: Yes you can, but as I don't use dreamhost, nor you explained how it works, I cannot help you.

Comment: What webhost do you use?

Comment: It's only a trial for dreamhost

Comment: On DreamHost, I think you will need VPS service to run a node app (since node is a long running process).  Once you have that, you can then create a sub-domain on DreamHost and configure it to be served by your node server.  Or, you can set up your node server somewhere else, get a public IP address for that other location and then set use the DNS settings in whomever manages your domain to create a sub-domain and set it for the IP address of the other service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing here is DNS -- you want to have different subdomains run different applications -- this is very normal and common.

The way you accomplish this is via DNS records.

Where is your domain hosted? Some place like godaddy.com?

If so, what you'll need to do is this:

- Deploy your Node app somewhere (Heroku is a good choice).
- Create a DNS CNAME record in your DNS provider's web panel that points from nodeapp.brandon.com -> yourapponheroku.com -- this will make it so that if a user visits nodeapp.brandon.com, your Heroku app will get that request.
- Create a DNS A record for your root domain that points to dreamhost: (brandon.com -> xx.xx.xx.xx) (where xx.xx.xx.xx is your dreamhost IP address). This makes it work so that users who visit brandon.com will see your dreamhost pages.

Hope that helps!